# How to confirm file is in XML format?

Tags: java, xml

Using Java, is there a way to look at some content, say, String representation of a file and either confirm or deny that it represents an XML file?

What library would you chose to parse the file? Could you possibly provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the *quickest* way would be to see if it parses, particularly if you have a DTD/XSD. You can check for well-formedness without either using any of the normal XML parsing libs.

Otherwise, not really sure what you could do.

Comment: Is there a parser library you can recommend I look at?

Comment: @JAM There's so many... not sure what the current darling is; dom4j is easy, but maybe a little old. There's jdom, jaxb... I tend to use whatever is already in my project, so I'm pretty agnostic--others might have some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in the result of parsing, only in a yes/no indication of whether it is well-formed, then you should use a SAX parser; if you use the XMLFilter class as your supplied ContentHandler then all the information from the parser will be immediately discarded, and the process will terminate as soon as a syntax error is found.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just examine the root tag: `<?xml version="" ?>` to check whether it's XML. But if your looking to validate an XML document that has specified a schema or DTD, then just create a validating parser from one of the two JAXP parser factories: SAXParserFactory and DOMBuilderFactory. If your validating only, go with the SAX parser, as it has a smaller memory footprint.